# Libera IRC network returns SSL or TLS errors with irssi or weechat

Tags: ssl, irc

When I try to connect to Libera chat using IRSSI I get,

```
-!- Irssi: warning SSL handshake failed: Connection timed out
```

When I try to connect it with weechat I get

```
libera =!= | irc: TLS handshake failed
libera =!= | irc: error: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
libera  -- | irc: reconnecting to server in 1 minute, 20 seconds
```

What's the problem, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is likely that you're **NOT** connecting to `irc.libera.chat`. In my case I was connecting to `irc.libera.net` instead.